# Angular 6 POST response - empty array, different then in Postman

Tags: json, angular, http, xmlhttprequest

We are using POST method in order to get data because I have to send complex filter as object in body.

### Postman response

Here is my situation.
Endpoint is responding with json object and in postman it returns all data like this

```
{
    filters: {...},
    supplements: [{...}, {...}],
    total: 2
}
```

[image]

So, everything fine here. There are three properties: filter - complex object, supplements - array with resulted objects, total - number of result, needed because results are paginated.

### Angular 6 http response

Anyway if I trigger exact same request through angular common/http everything same but supplements array gets empty like this

[image: Loged results]

And text version of results logged in console

```
{
    filter: {…},
    supplements: [],
    total: 2
}
```

Total 2 results but array is empty ?!

### Request code used

Here is a service where I got those results

```
getAll(keyword: string, page: number, size: number, body: object = {}) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        })
    };

    return this.http.post(
        this.url + `/supplements?keyword=${keyword}&page=${page}&size=${size}`,
    body,
    httpOptions
    ).subscribe(
        searchResults => {

            // Get relevant search results data
            console.log('results', searchResults);
            console.log('Total', searchResults['supplements'].length); // This gives 0
        });
```

In postman it is also 'Content-Type':  'application/json', and body is {}. I also tried to stringify body, nothing changed.

### Additional info

- Back-end written in Spring Rest
- From localhost I am using corsproxy, but if I use corsproxy in postman like this http://localhost:1337/localhost:8080/search/supplements?keyword=garden&page=0&size=10 again all is good
- arrays inside filter object in response are also fulfilled, just supplements array is empty
- Also tried to run app in prod mode, no difference

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide the request as text, not as a picture.

Comment: can you add postman screenshot also?

Comment: @trichetriche Actually on that picture is response which I console logged. Request is this url: {{ serverUrl }}/search/supplements?keyword=garden&page=0&size=10  body: {}, header:  {'Content-Type': '[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]'}

Comment: I don't care about what's in the picture, I can't see it. That's why I'm telling you to post your picture as text, because some people can't see pictures. And since requests are translated to text, copy-pasting shouldn't be that hard to perform.

Comment: @RahulSharma screenshot added  -  Please let me know if you need some more details